# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

//Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

//Says the error is on the first line. I'm really new to this and no clue. Any ideas?

```
dropit:function(obj, e, dropmenuID){
    if (this.dropmenuobj!=null) //hide previous menu
        this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility="hidden" //hide menu
    this.clearhidemenu()
    if (this.ie||this.firefox){
        obj.onmouseout=function(){cssdropdown.delayhidemenu()}
        obj.onclick=function(){return !cssdropdown.disablemenuclick} //disable main menu item link onclick?
        this.dropmenuobj=document.getElementById(dropmenuID)
        this.dropmenuobj.onmouseover=function(){cssdropdown.clearhidemenu()}
        this.dropmenuobj.onmouseout=function(e){cssdropdown.dynamichide(e)}
        this.dropmenuobj.onclick=function(){cssdropdown.delayhidemenu()}
        this.showhide(this.dropmenuobj.style, e)
        this.dropmenuobj.x=this.getposOffset(obj, "left")
        this.dropmenuobj.y=this.getposOffset(obj, "top")
        this.dropmenuobj.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.x-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "rightedge")+"px"
        this.dropmenuobj.style.top=this.dropmenuobj.y-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "bottomedge")+obj.offsetHeight+1+"px"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well is this a part of an object?

Comment: Pro-tip since you're new: Indent your code by blocks. Every time you put in a `{` the next line should be indented one more level. Every time you enter a `}` you should remove a layer of indentation on the next line. By indent, I mean hit`Tab` or hit `Space` 2 or 4 times (your preference). It makes your code easier to read and easier to debug.

Comment: Are you *writing* this code or are you trying to cut-and-paste?

Answer (score 3):

If that's really the first line of your code, then the problem is that it's syntactically incorrect. What is it that you expect

```
dropit:function(obj, e, dropmenuID){
```

to mean? It looks like a labeled statement, but that's not a valid place for a label. The unexpected token is the colon (`:`).

You can start fixing it by getting rid of `dropit:`, but I suspect that the problem is bigger than just that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pointy's answer, you appear to be missing braces on your first if statement.

Comment: You don't need braces if your `if` statement only has one statement to run after words. Ex: `if (true) console.log("I'll run"); console.log("So will I");`